# Word counter desktop application in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, desktop-application

I'm making a word counter desktop application in ASP.NET C#. For making this I'm using:

```
=> String str = txt_box.Text;  
=> Char[] space={' '};  
=> int word_count = str.Split(space,StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEnteries).Length;  
=> MessageBox.show(" Number of words = " + word_count);
```

The program calculates words properly, but when I press the Enter key, it does not count the word which is entered just after pressing the Enter key.

Example:

1)Hi, my name is Satpreet Singh
2)I'm a .NET Developer

Output: Number of words = 9

Explanation:

In this output, (Actual is 10 but it's showing 9)
                   When I press the Enter Key 
                   after typing the word "Singh" it can't split. It 
                   was merged with the word "I'm".

Comment: Desktop application in Asp.net?

Comment: You can add CR ('\n') to the collection of word separators (`spaces`)

Comment: You are splitting by space only but you should also split by new line character ('\n') as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in ASP.NET, but you could try the following,
Make a string, use LINQ to remove all non letter characters, split the string on all the whitespaces into an array, print the length of the array

```
string str = "Hi, my name is Satpreet Singh\nI'm a .NET Developer";
str = new string((from c in str
                  where char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)
                  select c
).ToArray());

string[] splitted = str.Split(new char[0]);
Console.WriteLine(splitted.Length);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output: 10